# Entity Framework 4 Self Join - Lazy loading both Parent object and Child Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, self-join

I'm trying to implement self join with entity framework 4, my use case as follow:

```
public class Category
{
    /// <summary>
    /// category id
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CatID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// category name
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Vui lòng nhập tên.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage="Tên chỉ có độ dài tối đa 100 ký tự.")]
    public string CatName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// parent category id
    /// self join :)
    /// </summary>
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// parent category
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// products list
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// categories which are associate with this category
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, child category will reference to parent category via `ParentID` foreign key. With this implement I was able to lazy load `ParentCategory` by using `Foreign Key` attribute. But child collection `Categories` was not being lazy load. How can I force lazy load child collection?

**EDIT**

If I didn't filter the result set lazy loading for both parent and child collection will work properly:

```
var cat = context.Category.ToList();
```

Buf if I filter the result set, child collection will not be lazy loaded

```
var cat = from entity in context.Category
          where entity.Parent == null
          select entity;
//child collection will be null
```

Comment: You can't, it should be enabled by default. Check that you are not doing something like `Include(...)` on your code. Also are you sure it is not lazy loaded? Do you actually see a single SQL query fired into the DB?

Comment: I did not use any include in my code. Child collections always null where it should have value

Comment: Question update! Please take a look and help me

Answer (score 0):

use "Include" methode for loading the Collection:

```
var selectedList = entity.where(m=>m.parent==null).include(m=>m.Categories).tolist();
```

Comment: I want to make it lazy load instead of eager load using `Include` method. But thank you for your attention, anw